# Contador de rotações unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, transform

Estou estudando o jogo Flippy Knife, e utilizei o AddRelativeTorque para fazer o giro da faca e aplicar o 360 que sempre soma 1 ponto, porém ao tentar fazer a contagem da pontuação checando se a faca ja atingiu determinado angulo, simplesmente não adicionava pontuação alguma (tentei varios angulos para ver se funcionava, mas não dava certo)
O angulo começa zerado, fiz o contador rodar no update, o que notei foi que no inspector, ao rodar o jogo, o rotation.x não vai de 0 a 360 por algum motivo, ele funciona de uma forma diferente.

Codigo do torque: (funciona conforme eu arrasto o mouse)

```
void Launch()
{
    isInAir = true;
    knifeRb.isKinematic = false;
    knifeRb.AddForce((releasePosition - touchPosition) * launchForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    knifeRb.AddRelativeTorque(torqueForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Contador (coloquei ele no update para rodar):

```
void Contador()
{
    if (contAng.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x == 359)
    {
        pontos++;            
    }

}
```

> [image: Jogo inicia com rotação no X zerada]

Comment: Não entendi... ele só vai somar `pontos` se o ângulo for exatamente 359?

Answer (score 0):

Acho que seria mais facil você fazer uma equação que calcule quantas vezes a faca girou ao invez de incrementar sempre que ela girar. pode fazer algo assim.

```
void Contador()
{
   points = (int) contAng.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x/360     
}
```

Pode deixar esse metodo no update caso queira criar feed backs cada vez que o valor do points mude ou pode chamar esse metodo no final pra saber quantas voltas deu.